# how to say "follow up appointment" in Japanese

Tags: words, daily-life

I have been trying to find the correct way to say 'follow up appointment' in Japanese. I have to go to the dermatologist for a follow up appointment and I am unsure what to say to the receptionist. I understand 予約 is 'appointment', what can I say for follow up appointment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can say [再診](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%86%8D%E8%A8%BA)の予約. For example, you can say 再診の予約をお願いします, 再診の予約をしたいのですが, 再診の予約が来週入っています, 初診ですか再診ですか, 今日は再診で来ました, and so on. フォローアップ or simply フォロー would make sense, too, but it sounds like medical jargon.